# AS3: if(ac is ArrayCollection){do things} but how to do if is not an ArrayCollection?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
if(ac is ArrayCollection){do things}
```

I want something like that

```
if(ac is not ArrayCollection){do things}
```

but how?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if(!(ac is ArrayCollection)){do things}